# Why is this specific API request failing when sending via wp_remote_post?

Tags: php, api, http-api, wp-remote-request

I'm pulling my hair out trying to make a POST request to an API endpoint using `wp_remote_post`.

The API needs a request with content-type `multipart/mixed` but WordPress doesn't seem to play nicely with that request type. It seems to be doing something to the POST body which causes the server to reject it. The response I receive is `400 Bad Request` (nothing specific).

The request works fine when made via cURL or Postman. Moreover, other API requests made via WordPress to the same API (e.g. POST requests with type `application/json`) work fine so I know it's not a problem with connectivity/authorization, or user-agent issues on the API side.

I suspect WordPress is making changes to the headers or the body somehow before sending the request, or just isn't sending the body as "raw" data.

Here's the code:

```php
$body = "--boundary
Content-Type: application/http

GET /foo/bar
--boundary
Content-Type: application/http

GET /bar/baz
--boundary--";

$endpoint = "https://example.com/api";

$options = [
    'body'        => $body,
    'headers'     => [
        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/mixed; boundary=--boundary',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer sometoken',
    ],
    'data_format' => 'body'
];

wp_remote_post( $endpoint, $options );
```

Here is an example of the same cURL request from Postman which **works** when submitted via Postman or via cURL's command line:

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/api \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer sometoken' \
    -H 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;  boundary=boundary' \
    -d '--boundary
Content-Type: application/http

GET /foo/bar
--boundary
Content-Type: application/http

GET /bar/baz
--boundary--
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Those with eagle eyes may have noticed that in the PHP code, the boundary string inside the `Content-Type` header was prefixed with two dashes (`--`).

Those dashes should have not been there. Removing them allows the request to work.

‍♂️